# extract day from Date

Tags: java, date

I receive a timestamp from a [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) service in milliseconds. So I do this:

```
Date date = new Date( mar.getEventDate() );
```

How can I extract the day of the month from date, since methods such as [`Date::getDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay()) are deprecated?

I am using a small hack, but I do not think this is the proper way to obtain day-of-month.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd" );
int day = Integer.parseInt( sdf.format( date ) );
```

Comment: Use [the Java Calendar class for this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 36):

Use [`Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(mar.getEventDate());
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

See the [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30829841/642706) by Ortomala Lokni, using the modern *java.time* classes. I am leaving this outmoded Answer intact as history.

---

The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30829841/642706) by Lokni is correct.

Here is the same idea but using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.8.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = mar.getEventDate() ;
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ;  // Or DateTimeZone.UTC
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( millisSinceEpoch , zone ) ;
int dayOfMonth = localDate.getDayOfMonth() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the [Date constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-) used in the question

```
Date date = new Date(mar.getEventDate());
```

The method `mar.getEventDate()` returns a `long` that  represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

## Java 8 and later

In Java 8, you can extract the day of the month from this value, assuming UTC, with

```
LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(mar.getEventDate(),0,ZoneOffset.UTC).getDayOfMonth();
```

Note also that the answer given by cletus assume that `mar.getEventDate()` returns a [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object which is not the case in the question.

Comment: Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).