# how to find the day in the month in java?

Tags: java, date

this is what i do to get date in java :

```
Date date = (new GregorianCalendar(year,month - 1, i)).getTime(); // year,month,day
            SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            nameofday = f.format(date);
```

when i print the date Object it gives me the answer like follows :

```
Sun Apr 01 00:00:00 IST 2012
Mon Apr 02 00:00:00 IST 2012
Tue Apr 03 00:00:00 IST 2012
Wed Apr 04 00:00:00 IST 2012
Thu Apr 05 00:00:00 IST 2012
Fri Apr 06 00:00:00 IST 2012
Sat Apr 07 00:00:00 IST 2012
```

from this i want to get only the day ex: 01,02,03,04,05,etc.

How to do this in java?

Regards
Tony

Comment: Do you mean format the output (as a string), or into a new object?

Comment: Please, have a look at other questions before asking, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619691/extract-day-from-date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the day as a number, use:

```
int dayOfMonth = gregorianCalendarInstance.get(Calendar.DATE);
```

If you want a string like `"05"`, change your date format to `dd`, that is:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your output is not the `nameofday`. If you printed `nameofday`, it would print "saturday" or "friday". If you want the day in the month on two characters, as indicated in the [javadoc of SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you must use `"dd"` for the pattern:

```
Date date = ...
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

You should really learn to read documentation.